# JSONObject(String) constructor is undefined, even though its in the docs

Tags: android, json

from the android documentation:
"

```
 JSONObject(String json)
```

Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string."

however my eclipse is complaining that such constructor doesnt exist when I do this:

```
InputStream ins = appContext.getResources().getAssets().open("bar-data.json");

byte[] bytes = new byte[ins.available()];
ins.read(bytes);
String string = new String(bytes);
JSONObject jsonobj = JSONObject(string);
```

error: 
The method JSONObject(String) is undefined for the type BarPage

(barPage is the name of my activity)

edit: this is the library in importing:

import org.json.JSONObject;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to put the "new" keyword on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the last line in your code as mentioned by Joe Minichino above. Additionally, you need to use the org.json.JSONObject jar. If you are using Maven, you can download it from here - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211. If you are having eclipse organize your imports, it picks up the JSON simple jar by default, namely org.json.simple.JSONObject, in which case passing a String argument to the JSONObject constructor won't work.

Comment: OP is developing android, the org.json library is included in the platform, no?